# How to more compactly test the condition for while loops in which the existence of (string)0 is checked?

Tags: php, string, while-loop, conditional-statements

In a few PHP applications I have written, there are functions which, given a starting string of variable length/content, whittle down the original string and simultaneously map this string to a separate new string:

```
$x = 'anything';
$mappedString = '';

while($x) {

    list($append, $cutPos) = mapping_function($x);

    $mapped_string.= $append;

    $x = substr($x, $cutPos); // whittle this string down to nothing, when empty($x) ---> mapping is complete

}

echo $mappedString; // newly mapped string
```

This general strategy has served me well until recently, in which I noticed problems when the last whittled-down substring of $x is the *string* 0. Here is a fake example which demonstrates the point:

Suppose you have an odd-length string that you map and cut 2 characters at a time:

```
$x = 'xxyyzz1';
$mappedString = '';
$i = 1;
while($x) {

    $remLength = strlen($x);

    if ($remLength > 1) {
        $mappedString .= "iteration" . $i . "_";
        $startPos = 2;
    } else {
        $mappedString .= "final iteration";
        $startPos = 1;
    }

    $x = substr($x, $startPos);
    //if (strlen($x) < 2) die(var_dump($x));
    $i++;

}

echo $mappedString; // the output is the following string ---> iteration1_iteration2_iteration3_final iteration
```

However, change the starting $x very slightly and now the output is not as intended:

```
$x = 'xxyyzz0'; // the 1 changed to a 0
$mappedString = '';
$i = 1;
while($x) {

    $remLength = strlen($x);

    if ($remLength > 1) {
        $mappedString .= "iteration" . $i . "_";
        $startPos = 2;
    } else {
        $mappedString .= "final iteration";
        $startPos = 1;
    }

    $x = substr($x, $startPos);
    //if (strlen($x) < 2) die(var_dump($x));
    $i++;
}    

echo $mappedString; // the output is the string ---> iteration1_iteration2_iteration3_
```

In other words, the final iteration, in which *$x has been whittled down to **0***, is not registering when the while loop tests $x:

```
while($x) ---> fails when $x = "0"
```

Note this happens even though this line

```
 if (strlen($x) < 2) die(var_dump($x));
```

when uncommented yields this:

```
string(1) "0"
```

Disappointingly, changing the while test condition to

```
while((string)$x) {
```

or

```
while(!empty($x))
```

yields the same result, and even changing this line:

```
$x = substr($x, $startPos);
```

to this:

```
$x = (string)substr($x, $startPos);
```

STILL gives the same result ---> iteration1_iteration2_iteration3_

It is only when I change the while condition to this less compact expression:

```
while(strlen($x) > 0) {
```

that this loop outputs the expected value ---> iteration1_iteration2_iteration3_final iteration

*How could I more compactly test for '0' in the while condition?*

Comment: About `while($x) ---> fails when $x = "0"` may do `while(strlen($x))`

Comment: Look here and write it fully to you mid: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php  and create an solution from that if you want a better approach as just `while(strlen($x))`

Comment: @thebluefox ... nothing is outputted when using $x === true

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions, !empty() does not yield the expected result and isset() causes an infinite loop

Comment: This can also work: `while(preg_match('#^.+$#',$x))`

Comment: I need speed of execution and I was already unhappy about needing while loops - preg_match() will make worse

Comment: @The One and Only ChemistryBlob Dont get it, i have never sayed something about `!empty() ` and `isset()`, can you explain? And by the way i know that `empty/isset` wont work here and why, all explained in the link above.

Comment: Because `$x` is never `=== true`.  Ignore that comment it is wrong.

Comment: I didn't think of strlen($x) - is good but I wish I didn't need to use a function at all

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions - look for $x = "0"; in first table of link you provided

Comment: `isset()` checks if a variable exists (in a way, not only for the value `unset($x); var_dump(isset($x))` gives `false`) and `empty()` works as expected, becuase `0` is no real value so it is empty, like `empty(array())` also true, because the array is empty. Keep in mind that PHP is NOT type save, and so some function work unexpected if you are not using it right.

Comment: Yes, but $x = (string)0 not (int)0

Comment: No, do not thing in that way. Most functions will CAST the input value too the needed format. Did you know that `$x='123abc'; print (int)$x;` becomes `123`? Go always the save way to rome.... , check for the length of the string is currently the best solution here.

Comment: And `while($x)` will always CAST the `$x` like `(bool)$x` and `(bool)0` (string or int) will become `false`

Comment: OK - thanks. I didn't know while will cast $x